# Consume raw json queue messages in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Normally Laravel expects that it queued up any messages that it later consumes. It creates a payload with a `job` attribute that later indicates how to handle the queue message. When you do queue up jobs with Laravel, and later process them with Laravel, it works great!

However, I have some non-Laravel apps that are posting json messages to a queue. I need Laravel to pick up these messages and handle them.

I can write a command bus job to handle the messages, but I haven't been able to figure out how to tell `queue:work` to send the messages on to my specific handler.

It seems Laravel has a hard assumption that any queue messages it is asked to handle will be properly formatted, serialized, and structured the way it expects them to be.

How can I have Laravel pick up these raw json payloads, ignore the structure (there's nothing there for it to understand), and simply hand the payload off to my handler?

For example, if I have a queue message similar to:

```
{
    "foo" : "bar"
}
```

So again, there's *nothing* for Laravel to inspect or understand here.

But I have a job handler that knows how to handle this:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

class MyQueueHandler {
    public function handle($payload) {
        Log::info($payload['foo']); // yay!
    }
}
```

Now how to get `queue:work` and `queue:listen` to simply hand off any payloads to this `App\Jobs\MyQueueHandler` handler, where I can do the rest on my own?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Laravel 5.6+, check out [this package](https://github.com/pawprintdigital/laravel-queue-raw-sqs).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version of Laravel, so I'm guessing 5.1 (huge difference in how this is handled in L4.2 and L5.x).

If you've already set up your `App\Jobs\MyQueueHandler`, and want to queue up a job from a controller, using any data you wish, you can just do this:

```
use App\Jobs\MyQueueHandler;

class MyController 
{
    public function myFunction() 
    {
        $this->dispatch(new MyQueueHandler(['foo' => 'bar']));
    }
}
```

In your `MyQueueHandler`-class, the payload actually enters your constructor. The handle-method is still fired when your queue is processed though. You can however use parameters on your `handle`-method if you rely on dependancy injection ([read more here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes), just above "*When Things Go Wrong*") So something like this should do it:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

class MyQueueHandler 
{

    protected $payload;

    public function __construct($payload)
    {
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }

    public function handle() {
        Log::info($this->payload['foo']); // yay!
    }
}
```

Note: If you want to dispatch the job from outside a main controller (that inherits from the standard `App\Http\Controller`-class, use the `DispatchesJobs` trait;

```
MyClass 
{
    use DispatchesJobs;

    public function myFunction()
    {
        $this->dispatch(new MyQueueHandler(['foo' => 'bar']));
    }
}
```

(Code tested with Laravel 5.1.19 and the beanstalkd queue-adapter).

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is not possible as Laravel tries to execute the Gearman payload (see `\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher`).

I was in the same situation and just created a wrapper `command` around the Laravel job class. This is not the nicest solution as it will re-queue events, coming on the json queue, but you don't have to touch existing job classes. Maybe someone with more experience knows how to dispatch a job without actually sending it over the wire again.

Lets assume we have one regular Laravel worker class called `GenerateIdentApplicationPdfJob`.

```
class GenerateIdentApplicationPdfJob extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    /** @var User */
    protected $user;

    protected $requestId;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * QUEUE_NAME = 'ident-pdf';
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @param      $requestId
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, $requestId)
    {
        $this->user      = $user;
        $this->requestId = $requestId;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Client $client)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To be able to handle this class, we need to provide the constructor arguments our own. Those are the required data from our json queue.

Below is a Laravel `command` class `GearmanPdfWorker`, which does all the boilerplate of Gearman connection and `json_decode` to be able to handle the original job class.

```
class GearmanPdfWorker extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'pdf:worker';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'listen to the queue for pdf generation jobs';

    /**
     * @var \GearmanClient
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @var \GearmanWorker
     */
    private $worker;

    public function __construct(\GearmanClient $client, \GearmanWorker $worker) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->worker = $worker;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper listener for gearman jobs with plain json payload
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $gearmanHost = env('CB_GEARMAN_HOST');
        $gearmanPort = env('CB_GEARMAN_PORT');

        if (!$this->worker->addServer($gearmanHost, $gearmanPort)) {
            $this->error('Error adding gearman server: ' . $gearmanHost . ':' . $gearmanPort);
            return 1;
        } else {
            $this->info("added server $gearmanHost:$gearmanPort");
        }

        // use a different queue name than the original laravel command, since the payload is incompatible
        $queueName = 'JSON.' . GenerateIdentApplicationPdfJob::QUEUE_NAME;
        $this->info('using queue: ' . $queueName);

        if (!$this->worker->addFunction($queueName,
            function(\GearmanJob $job, $args) {
                $queueName = $args[0];
                $decoded = json_decode($job->workload());
                $this->info("[$queueName] payload: " . print_r($decoded, 1));

                $job = new GenerateIdentApplicationPdfJob(User::whereUsrid($decoded->usrid)->first(), $decoded->rid);
                $job->onQueue(GenerateIdentApplicationPdfJob::QUEUE_NAME);
                $this->info("[$queueName] dispatch: " . print_r(dispatch($job)));
            },
            [$queueName])) {
            $msg = "Error registering gearman handler to: $queueName";
            $this->error($msg);
            return 1;
        }

        while (1) {
            $this->info("Waiting for job on `$queueName` ...");
            $ret = $this->worker->work();
            if ($this->worker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS) {
                $this->error("something went wrong on `$queueName`: $ret");
                break;
            }
            $this->info("... done `$queueName`");
        }
    }
}
```

The class `GearmanPdfWorker` needs to be registered in your `\Bundle\Console\Kernel` like this:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        // ...
        \Bundle\Console\Commands\GearmanPdfWorker::class
    ];
    
    // ...
```

Having all that in place, you can call `php artisan pdf:worker` to run the worker and put one job into Gearman via commandline: `gearman -v -f JSON.ident-pdf '{"usrid":9955,"rid":"ABC4711"}'`

You can see the successful operation then

```
added server localhost:4730
using queue: JSON.ident-pdf
Waiting for job on `JSON.ident-pdf` ...
[JSON.ident-pdf] payload: stdClass Object
(
    [usrid] => 9955
    [rid] => ABC4711
)

0[JSON.ident-pdf] dispatch: 1
... done `JSON.ident-pdf`
Waiting for job on `JSON.ident-pdf` ...
```

Comment: I should have come back and updated. I ended up finding this package: https://github.com/kristianedlund/laravel-external-queue. Bit rough around the edges, but it worked. Allows me to pick up raw json payloads from SQS and hand them to a handler. I extended it pretty easily for IronMQ as well.

Comment: I'm struggling to implement that library (using rabbitmq), did you come across any code samples in your travels? thanks